# React-native doesn't update value

Tags: javascript, react-native

Today i have tried to create function that updates every next index of array. I used this code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import update from "immutability-helper";

export default function App() {
  const initialArray = [1, 2, 3];
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  var num = 0;
  function test() {
    num = num + 1;
    setArr(update(initialArray, { [num]: { $apply: () => 444 } })); 
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{arr}</Text>

      <Button title="change next index" onPress={() => test()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Unfortunately, **num = num + 1;** not working when call this function again and again? Where is problem?
I used this [lib](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

num is local variable in function so when your component re-renders it gets initialised with 0 again.

you can use useRef hook to store mutable value between re-renders.

```
export default function App() {
  const initialArray = [1, 2, 3];
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  const numRef = useRef(0);
  function test() {
    numRef.current = numRef.current + 1;
    setArr(update(initialArray, { [numRef.current]: { $apply: () => 444 } })); 
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{arr}</Text>

      <Button title="change next index" onPress={() => test()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Works as a expected. Thank youuu